# Python and XML (LandXML)

Tags: python, xml, tree, iteration

Ok, I have some XML file looks like this, actually it is LandXML file, but works like any other XML. I need to parse it with python (currently I'm using ElementTree lib) in that way to cycle through sub-element `<CoordGeom></CoordGeom>` and make lists dependent on child - it can be lineList, spiralList and curveList. Content of that lists is atribute values (don't need names) as nested list for every object. Something like:

```
lineList=[[10.014571204947,209.285340662374,776.719431311241 -399.949629732524,813.113864060552 -193.853052659974],[287.308329990254,277.363320844698,558.639337133827 380.929458057393,293.835705515579 463.448840215686]]
```

Here is a sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd" date="2015-05-15" time="09:47:43" version="1.2" language="English" readOnly="false">
    <Units>
        <Metric areaUnit="squareMeter" linearUnit="meter" volumeUnit="cubicMeter" temperatureUnit="celsius" pressureUnit="milliBars" diameterUnit="millimeter" angularUnit="decimal degrees" directionUnit="decimal degrees"></Metric>
    </Units>
    <Project name="C:\Users\Rade\Downloads\Situacija i profili.dwg"></Project>
    <Application name="AutoCAD Civil 3D" desc="Civil 3D" manufacturer="Autodesk, Inc." version="2014" manufacturerURL="www.autodesk.com/civil" timeStamp="2015-05-15T09:47:43"></Application>
    <Alignments name="">
        <Alignment name="Proba" length="1201.057158008475" staStart="0." desc="">
            <CoordGeom>
                <Line dir="10.014571204947" length="209.285340662374">
                    <Start>776.719431311241 -399.949629732524</Start>
                    <End>813.113864060552 -193.853052659974</End>
                </Line>
                <Spiral length="435.309621307305" radiusEnd="300." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="41.569006803911" totalY="101.382259815422" totalX="412.947724836996" tanLong="298.633648469722" tanShort="152.794210168398">
                    <Start>813.113864060552 -193.853052659974</Start>
                    <PI>865.04584458778 100.230482065888</PI>
                    <End>785.087350093002 230.433054310499</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Curve rot="cw" chord="150.078507004323" crvType="arc" delta="28.970510103309" dirEnd="299.475054297727" dirStart="328.445564401036" external="9.849481983234" length="151.689236185509" midOrd="9.536387074322" radius="300." tangent="77.502912753511">
                    <Start>785.087350093002 230.433054310499</Start>
                    <Center>529.44434090873 73.440532656728</Center>
                    <End>677.05771309169 334.61153478517</End>
                    <PI>744.529424397382 296.476647100012</PI>
                </Curve>
                <Spiral length="127.409639008589" radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="300." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="12.166724307463" totalY="8.989447716697" totalX="126.8363181841" tanLong="85.141254974713" tanShort="42.653117896421">
                    <Start>677.05771309169 334.61153478517</Start>
                    <PI>639.925187941987 355.598770007863</PI>
                    <End>558.639337133827 380.929458057393</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Line dir="287.308329990254" length="277.363320844698">
                    <Start>558.639337133827 380.929458057393</Start>
                    <End>293.835705515579 463.448840215686</End>
                </Line>
            </CoordGeom>
            <Profile name="Proba">
                <ProfAlign name="Niveleta">
                    <PVI>0. 329.48636525895</PVI>
                    <CircCurve length="69.993187715052" radius="5000.">512.581836381869 330.511528931714</CircCurve>
                    <CircCurve length="39.994027682446" radius="5000.">948.834372016349 337.491569501865</CircCurve>
                    <PVI>1201.057158008475 339.509351789802</PVI>
                </ProfAlign>
            </Profile>
        </Alignment>
    </Alignments>
</LandXML>
```

Comment: with XML, I've never used it. I learned about it past few days, but it's apparently not enough. Problem is how to get at `<CoordGeom></CoordGeom>` level and cycle through all elements and separate them into different lists of attributes :) or simply spoken - I'm struggling with everything

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: `coordGeom = root[3][0][0]`
`for obj in coordGeom:
 chList.Add(obj.tag)`

Comment: thats for getting object names like, spiral, line or curve, but how to get values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is far from production ready, but it should contain everything you need everything you need for implementing the full solution. This only searches for lines only, does not know which attributes it needs to look for on other kinds of geometry and hasn't got any kind of error handling.

And it's not pretty.

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('/tmp/stuff.xml')
geometry = doc.find('.//{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2}CoordGeom')

line_list = []

for child in geometry:
    child_list = []
    if child.tag == '{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2}Line':
        child_list.append(float(child.attrib['dir']))
        child_list.append(float(child.attrib['length']))

        start, end = child.find('{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2}Start'), child.find('{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2}End')
        child_list.extend([float(coord) for coord in start.text.split(' ')])
        child_list.extend([float(coord) for coord in end.text.split(' ')])

        line_list.append(child_list)

print line_list
```

If you want to extend this example, have a thorough read-thru of the [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html). Everything I've used is in the tutorial.

Comment: Tnx a lot, you have no idea how much you've helped me :) this works and also, it's great instruction for further development.

Comment: hm, it return me all elements with that attributes, not only line :/ to me, code looks ok, but I don't know why that happens. Maybe I should try lxml instead of basic ElementTree lib

Comment: Oh, I used lxml out of habit. Maybe post a new question with the code you have now and where the behaviour differs from what you're expecting?

Comment: Please don't try lxml, it will only confuse you. :-) Here is a solution that, I think, does everything you want using just standard library: http://pastebin.com/vrd6eFuS

Comment: @Veky That is a far superior version, kudos. Add it as an answer, you'll have my vote!